# Add existing SAML assertion to WS security header

Tags: java, xml, soap, saml, spring-ws

I'm using spring-ws (2.1.4) `WebServiceTemplate` with a custom `WebServiceMessageCallback` to insert the security header with a SAML which I will receive as a `org.w3c.dom.Element` and only create myself for testing.

I use `webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new HeaderCallback(ctx, uri))` to marshal and send my request.

My issue is that the verification of the signature fails on the server side, the digests don't match. Comparing the output of the SAML before sending and after receiving I see that on the receiving side I have namespace declarations on elements that didn't have one before sending.

What I currently do in my callback:

```
@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    super.doWithMessage(message);

    Assert.isInstanceOf(SoapMessage.class, message);
    SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
    SoapHeaderElement securityHeader = soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(WS_SECURITY_NAME);

    try {
        Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(assertion), securityHeader.getResult());
    } catch (org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can insert an element into a SOAP XML making sure that the element will not be modified? Or is there a different approach to achieve this using Spring `WebServiceTemplate`?

I came across `org.apache.ws.security.saml.ext.SAMLCallback` which has a method `setAssertionElement`, however I did not find out how to get this working with the `WebServiceTemplate` (respectively `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor`) particularly considering that I need to pass in an existing SAML assertion as a parameter.

**SAML XML before sending:**

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" IssueInstant="2015-09-23T09:46:14.357Z" Version="2.0">
<saml2:Issuer>iTEST</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>rVbvzGr4LI/Kd0c+kuhqkupSY44=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>TIbtFHnqURfko94eqANDX8UEhw0HSI3xL0sAQ5GbhjVn2DicckzxpoJL3RVPF6KhLOkUPm5IgnF5At6Es69D48DLE+QvWvP0F7VmcdNJHRSnzIWYaJsXfNfDt2AXXM1kanp5Gq8nj1EsT6C8SlkO1x77C3vKkn1nLSNszEkukuhEzA8V7G+l6L65bIveA36IyYqjiVDKIMOIzHMF9qK03Um7qJHWoxvxSig1UPBINlBtDqyhbGW01OnoHP8qXK7bzuP6p3zbBDhhEYMyNV2P8GT8zX1+cv+JE6ghde4K9hyf6V+x6L218L1AOjACEJUkBrxw0q1uJAVGA1UNJPJbJQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2:Subject>
<saml2:NameID>authSigner</saml2:NameID>
</saml2:Subject>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

**SAML XML after receiving:**

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" IssueInstant="2015-09-23T09:46:14.357Z" Version="2.0">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">iTEST</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:Reference URI="" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:Transforms xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">rVbvzGr4LI/Kd0c+kuhqkupSY44=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">TIbtFHnqURfko94eqANDX8UEhw0HSI3xL0sAQ5GbhjVn2DicckzxpoJL3RVPF6KhLOkUPm5IgnF5At6Es69D48DLE+QvWvP0F7VmcdNJHRSnzIWYaJsXfNfDt2AXXM1kanp5Gq8nj1EsT6C8SlkO1x77C3vKkn1nLSNszEkukuhEzA8V7G+l6L65bIveA36IyYqjiVDKIMOIzHMF9qK03Um7qJHWoxvxSig1UPBINlBtDqyhbGW01OnoHP8qXK7bzuP6p3zbBDhhEYMyNV2P8GT8zX1+cv+JE6ghde4K9hyf6V+x6L218L1AOjACEJUkBrxw0q1uJAVGA1UNJPJbJQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Certificate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2:Subject xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml2:NameID xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">authSigner</saml2:NameID>
</saml2:Subject>
</saml2:Assertion>
</wsse:Security>
```

---

**EDIT**: I found a way that does not add the additional namespaces. What I'm doing now is using the `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` and importing the node:

```
@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    super.doWithMessage(message);

    Assert.isInstanceOf(SaajSoapMessage.class, message);

    try {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) message).getSaajMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        if (soapEnvelope.getHeader() == null) {
            soapEnvelope.addHeader();
        }

        SOAPHeaderElement securityElement = soapEnvelope.getHeader().addHeaderElement(WS_SECURITY_NAME);
        securityElement.appendChild(soapPart.importNode(assertion, true));

    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }

}
```

**However**, even though the diff shows no difference between the outputs **the verification is still failing**. At this point I'm not sure if I can trust the output and that doing it like that really did not change the SAML...

Any ideas what else could cause the digests not to match?

Comment: Could you show us a before / after code fragment of the XML?

Comment: What kind of message factory do you use? SAAJ or Axiom?

Comment: I'm using `SaajSoapMessageFactory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach (which I already documented on my question as an edit) prevented additional namespaces from being added.

```
@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    super.doWithMessage(message);

    Assert.isInstanceOf(SaajSoapMessage.class, message);

    try {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) message).getSaajMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        if (soapEnvelope.getHeader() == null) {
            soapEnvelope.addHeader();
        }

        SOAPHeaderElement securityElement = soapEnvelope.getHeader().addHeaderElement(WS_SECURITY_NAME);
        securityElement.appendChild(soapPart.importNode(assertion, true));

    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }

}
```

I also got the SAML validation to work. It had nothing to do with the way the SAML was added to the SOAP message (also my original approach using `Transformer`- even though it adds the additional namespaces - validates now). Missing was the ID on the assertion.

Here's how my SAML looks now:

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_63ecd7ce7163507e56270edcd644494b" IssueInstant="2015-09-24T18:23:15.118Z" Version="2.0">
<saml2:Issuer>iTEST</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#_63ecd7ce7163507e56270edcd644494b">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>yjlkSOIJC3qNYzEYfipGIwoAD9A=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>fIEp5aYFVesexZWAfMM+e8kcwe52nl54xMr92wtz2BZ3TIVkY6u5vfh8hA0q6hkzEEaHV5vM0cEXholekn4og41jhMn7XwmScggrbr/neYBMdE95GRz6Nv2Sc6PzqPTYeFp+Dylho7sy1yZtWAb3jiGm8zdHJIQuk6NNUZhnMPkZqjXpM68U9cRGojAmnczbRVl2couxDp5fErivKJgJuffN3FVBfCFrFOjGpVf00ukZxqJJ3RP+n7wXWl251W0i0KvWCZPCD5gzl69EzNFc78o8khzd26aLIeDFLBQr0BPnrC454dZZ/SSNeH52HtDstNJ6SBrWFAA8c8vnLSJ0fg==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2:Subject>
<saml2:NameID>authSigner</saml2:NameID>
</saml2:Subject>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

Comment: A follow up question, if you have an Assertion java object that has been signed already, how do you convert it into DOM element and insert it into the existing SOAP Envelope Security header?